# ViewHolder views must not be attached

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am new at android programming. I have an application which can insert into the cloud firestore it also needs to read the data in the Cloud Firestore. It keeps crashing when I am trying to open the activity where I read the data. The logcat gives this error

```
2021-01-12 21:20:56.733 25524-25524/com.example.ppw1 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.ppw1, PID: 25524
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ViewHolder views must not be attached when created. Ensure that you are not passing 'true' to the attachToRoot parameter of LayoutInflater.inflate(..., boolean attachToRoot)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7080)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6235)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6118)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6114)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2303)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1627)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1587)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:665)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4134)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3851)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.consumePendingUpdateOperations(RecyclerView.java:1897)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$1.run(RecyclerView.java:414)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:871)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:683)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:616)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:857)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

My code is:

```js
package com.example.ppw1;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerOptions;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.CollectionReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.Query;

public class ListActivities extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    private CollectionReference todoRef = db.collection("users");
    private ToDoAdapter adapter;
    private RecyclerView mFirestoreList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_activities);

        this.setTitle("List Activity");

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        setUpRecyclerView();

        mFirestoreList = findViewById(R.id.firestore_list);
    }

    private void setUpRecyclerView()
    {
        Query query = todoRef.whereEqualTo("Email", mAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail());

        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<ToDoItem> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<ToDoItem>().setQuery(query,ToDoItem.class).build();


        adapter = new ToDoAdapter(options);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.firestore_list);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop()
    {
        super.onStop();
        adapter.stopListening();
    }
}
```

My DoToAdapter code which is handling most of the query I am thinking error must be one of those classes but I am not sure.

```js
package com.example.ppw1;

import android.text.format.DateUtils;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerOptions;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Request;

public class ToDoAdapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<ToDoItem, ToDoAdapter.ToDoHolder> {

  // Listener listene r;

    /**
     * Create a new RecyclerView adapter that listens to a Firestore Query.  See {@link
     * FirestoreRecyclerOptions} for configuration options.
     *
     * @param options
     */
    public ToDoAdapter(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<ToDoItem> options) {
        super(options);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ToDoHolder holder, int position, @NonNull ToDoItem model) {

        holder.title.setText(model.getTitle());
        holder.description.setText(model.getDesc());

       // String timeAgo = (String) DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(model.getTimeAdded().getSeconds())*1000;
      // holder.dateAdded.setText(timeAgo);


    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ToDoHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_to_do_item, parent);

        return new ToDoHolder(v);
    }


    class ToDoHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView title, description, dateAdded;


        public ToDoHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.todoTitle);
            description = itemView.findViewById(R.id.todoDesc);
           // dateAdded = itemView.findViewById(R.id.dateAdded);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you post you Adapter code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ViewHolder views must not be attached when created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51099529/viewholder-views-must-not-be-attached-when-created)

Comment: I just edited my post

Comment: There should be some further information in your stacktrace.

Comment: yes I do have. I have edited the post with all of the errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: ViewHolder views must not be attached when created. Ensure that you are not passing 'true' to the attachToRoot parameter of LayoutInflater.inflate(..., boolean attachToRoot)

The default value of the `attachToRoot` is true if the `ViewGroup` parameter is not `null` please see [the 2-arg inflate method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater#inflate(int,%20android.view.ViewGroup)):

```
public View inflate(@LayoutRes int resource, @Nullable ViewGroup root) {
    return inflate(resource, root, root != null);
}
```

So, you need to use [the 3-arg `inflate()`method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater#inflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser,%20android.view.ViewGroup)) to set the third `attachToRoot` parameter to `false` when you inflate the item layout within `onCreateViewHolder()`

```
@NonNull
@Override
public ToDoHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_to_do_item, parent, false);

    return new ToDoHolder(v);
}
```

> **attachToRoot** Whether the inflated hierarchy should be attached to
> the root parameter? If false, root is only used to create the
> correct subclass of LayoutParams for the root view in the XML.

Comment: Thanks now it is working but it is not returning with any data. Any idea what might be causing this ?

Comment: Do you have any exceptions when you run it?

Comment: No doesn't give any errors but comes with RecyclerView comes with empty data.

Comment: Can you change `private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();` to `private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().getReference();`